# Calculate the length of a row in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to identify the total amount of time reported by id from t1 till t7. T1 that records the occurrence of an activity during day1 at different timesteps such as t1_1 , t1_2, t1_3 and so on. I am intrested only in consecutive w days. A consecutive day means that the id reported activity at t1 and t2; a none consecutive  means activity reported during t1 and t3.  I would like to identify the id's that reported activity from t1 to t7 as well the amount of time that was reported

Input:

```
id t1_1 t1_2 t1_3 t2_1 t2_2 t2_3 t3_1 t3_2 t3_3 t4_1 t4_2 t4_3 t5_1 t5_2 t5_3 t6_1 t6_2 t6_3 t7_1 t7_2 t7_3
12  0    1     1    0     1   0    1    0    1    0    1    0    0    1    0     1   1     1   0      0  1
123 0    0     0    1     1   1    0    0    0    1    1    1    1    1    1     0   0     0    1     1  1
 10  1   1     1    1     1    1    1   1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1   1     1    1     1  1
```

Output for id 12

```
Id   Duration  
12        11                  
10        21
```

One way to dot this is using the bioconductor, subseting the data on daily level but are there any better solution?

Sample data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = c(12L, 123L, 10L), t1_1 = c(0L, 0L, 1L), 
            t1_2 = c(1L, 0L, 1L), t1_3 = c(1L, 0L, 1L), t2_1 = c(0L, 
            1L, 1L), t2_2 = c(1L, 1L, 1L), t2_3 = c(0L, 1L, 1L), t3_1 = c(1L, 
            0L, 1L), t3_2 = c(0L, 0L, 1L), t3_3 = c(1L, 0L, 1L), t4_1 = c(0L, 
            1L, 1L), t4_2 = c(1L, 1L, 1L), t4_3 = c(0L, 1L, 1L), t5_1 = c(0L, 
            1L, 1L), t5_2 = c(1L, 1L, 1L), t5_3 = c(0L, 1L, 1L), t6_1 = c(1L, 
            0L, 1L), t6_2 = c(1L, 0L, 1L), t6_3 = c(1L, 0L, 1L), t7_1 = c(0L, 
            1L, 1L), t7_2 = c(0L, 1L, 1L), t7_3 = c(1L, 1L, 1L)), 
            class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
        -3L))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution with `data.table`, but the same could be achived with `dplyr`. I first partially tranform to long format:

```
library(data.table)
df1 <- setDT(df1)
df2 <- melt(df1,measure.vars = patterns(paste0("t",1:7)),variable.name = "time",value.name = paste0("day",1:7))

    id time day1 day2 day3 day4 day5 day6 day7
1:  12    1    0    0    1    0    0    1    0
2: 123    1    0    1    0    1    1    0    1
3:  10    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
4:  12    2    1    1    0    1    1    1    0
5: 123    2    0    1    0    1    1    0    1
6:  10    2    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
7:  12    3    1    0    1    0    0    1    1
8: 123    3    0    1    0    1    1    0    1
9:  10    3    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
```

I then sum the time by day:

```
df3 <- df2[,lapply(.SD,sum),.SDcols = paste0("day",1:7),by = .(id)]

    id day1 day2 day3 day4 day5 day6 day7
1:  12    2    1    2    1    1    3    1
2: 123    0    3    0    3    3    0    3
3:  10    3    3    3    3    3    3    3
```

The duration can be foun with apply function, integrating your condition that none day should have 0 time worked:

```
duration <- apply(df3[,-"id"],1,function(x){if(all(x>0)){sum(x)}else{NA}}) %>% unlist()
output <- data.frame(id = df3$id[!is.na(duration)],duration = na.omit(duration))

  id duration
1 12       11
2 10       21
```

Comment: many thanks for your time, if you have time how can identify those id's that follow a consecutive order for 2, 3,4,5 and 6 day. For example in id 123  day4 and day5 are consecutive how can return the id based on number of occurrence and duration. I know that is a big ask but thank you